# css+html5 The best way to lay out this info

Tags: css, html

I want to lay out the following info horizontally in a container 460px wide:

32 Likes (Restricted to 50px wide)    (whitespace)      From Great Britain        (whitespace)                           Featured (Floated to the right)

What would you recommend being the best tags to use to lay these out?

You can see an image of what I mean here http://www.flickr.com/photos/62570778@N04/5693086371/in/dateposted/

Comment: That appears to be an incoherent collection of words. The choice of tags would depend on what the content is (heading? chapter number? count of something? links?), and I can't reverse engineer that from your example.

Comment: @kylle, edit your answer to be more clear. Don't leave your update in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that there are any new tags in HTML5 that would give semantic value to the data you're laying out.

A `div` would probably be the best element to use, along with a usual `hX` for the title and `strong` (or the like) for the Featured text.

Actually, if this is a list of link items, you could always use a `menu`/`li` layout? If you're also showing content from these posts(?), how about a `section` or `article` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think a picture would better describe what you mean.

I'm confused if the entire button is 50px wide in an arbitrary 460px wide block or if the content is in a 460px wide block, and the 32 Likes itself is 50px wide and From Great Britain Featured is to the right and are separate elements?

Comment: Image uploaded here http://www.flickr.com/photos/62570778@N04/5693086371/in/dateposted/

Comment: @kyllle so you're not *just* displaying this, there's other data on top/underneath? In that case you could use an `article` as in my answer.